# how to get admob's advertisement info in Android APP

Tags: sdk, admob, ads, adview

are there any way to get the advertisement info of admob in AdView or other class.

the advertisement info are include below:

if the advertisement is String, then get title, description, the url of click.
if the advertisement is picture, then get the Bitmap, the url of click.